# Vuetify 3: handle Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite, vuetifyjs3

I use Vuetify 3 and bootstrap the project with `npm create vuetify`, [as documented](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/).

Without changing anything in the code, it seems that there is an issue of FOUC (Flas of Unstyled Content). For some milliseconds, fonts are displayed in wrong size and icons are not rendered correctly.

[image]

This is easier to reproduce if using developer tools; for example, if using Chrome, in *Network tab*, disable cache and instead of *No throttling* choose a slower connection simulation (e.g. 3G).

This happens also on built projects, not only in development.

Is there any workaround? I try to render my page only after all CSS is loaded (something that I suppose should be handled by Vuetify) but with no success so far. For example, I tried listening to `loaded` event:

template:

```
<v-app v-show="isWindowReady">
...
</v-app>
```

script:

```
const isWindowReady = ref(false);

onMounted(() => {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        isWindowReady.value = true;
    });
});
```

As I said, it didn't work.

Any ideas / workarounds to avoid this behavior?